# How can i make an AjaxCall in which i can send some data(Text) to the server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

How can i make an `AjaxCall`  in which i can send some data(Text) to the server.

Here is my `AjaxCall`.

```
function AjaxCall() 
        {
               alert("ajax call made");
               sendAjaxRequest({ 'FUNCTION': 'Page_Load' }); 

       }
       function sendAjaxRequest(jsonData) {
           jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               async: "false",
               url: location.href,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: (jsonData),
               dataType: "text",
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   alert("Reply from Server: " + jqXHR.responseText);

               },
               error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert("Error: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
               },
               beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                   xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OFFICIAL-REQUEST-MINE", "TRUE"); 
               },
               complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
               }
           });
       }
```

My c# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.Headers["X-OFFICIAL-REQUEST-MINE"] == "TRUE")
   {
      AjaxWrapper(sender.ToString());
   }
}
protected void AjaxWrapper(string sender)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text";
    byte[] b = Response.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(sender);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());
    Response.Write(sender);            
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I want to modify this further so that i can send some text to the server. How can i do that?

Comment: What about the **Web Method** in asp.net...

Comment: Im not using a Web method. This C# code is part of a DotnetNuke Module so it directly executes the C# code